# Thread.join() not executing code to completion

Tags: java, multithreading, mutex

Im doing an assignment for uni and I am trying to get my program to execute multiple hill climber algorithms within parallel threads for a self-avoiding walk.

Not only that, it seems to be slowing down my computer a lot when I run it and uses up a lot of memory, which sometimes crashes the program. 
Another thing is that it works perfectly fine with just two threads, if you try deleting th3 it would work perfectly. Maybe the root cause is that there is too much memory being used with my code. In any case, I would appreciate any help you guys could give me. Thank you!

```
public class Assign3 extends JFrame{
    static Boolean gridd[][];
    static String best[];
    static int bestscore;
    private static final String sequence = "NESW";

    public Assign3() {
        //setup();
        gridd = new Boolean[3][5];
        for(int i = 0;i<gridd.length;i++) {
            for(int j = 0;j<gridd[i].length;j++) {
                gridd[i][j] = false;
            }
        }
        String s[] = generateS(14);//generates a random sequence of length 14 and splits it into an array 

        Boolean grid2[][] = run(gridd,s);
        bestscore = evaluate(grid2);//evaluates a board depending on how many vertices the sequence has visited

        printb(grid2,s);//prints the sequence, the board, and the score of the board

        Thread th = new mt(s);
        th.start();
        Thread th2 = new mt(s);
        th2.start();
        Thread th3 = new mt(s);
        th3.start();

        try {
            th.join();
            th2.join();
            th3.join();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("FLOPPPP");
        }
        printb(gridd,best);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { new Assign3(); 
    }

    public static Boolean[][] run(Boolean grid[][], String temp[]) {
        int x=0;
        int y=0;
        grid[x][y] = true;
        for(int i=0;i<temp.length;i++) {
            if(temp[i].indexOf('W')!=-1) {
                if(y==0)
                    return grid;
                else if(grid[x][y-1] ==true){
                    return grid;
                }
                else {
                    grid[x][y-1]=true;
                    y--;
                }
            }//There is similar code for the rest of the directions, but I thought I should save space
        }
        return grid;
    }

class mt extends Thread{

    private String[] s;
    private ReentrantLock mutex = new ReentrantLock();

    public mt(String[] s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Boolean g[][] = null;
        String temp[] = s;
        Boolean c = false;

        System.out.println(Assign3.bestscore);

        while(c==false) {
            Random r = new Random();
            int l = r.nextInt(s.length);
            int d = r.nextInt(4);
            String n = "";

            if(d==0)
                n="N";
            else if(d==1)
                n="E";
            else if(d==2)
                n="S";
            else if(d==3)
                n="W";

            temp[l] = n;

            g = Assign3.run(Assign3.gridd,temp);


            try {
                mutex.lock();
                try {
                    if(Assign3.evaluate(g)>Assign3.bestscore) {
                        c=true;
                        Assign3.bestscore = Assign3.evaluate(g);
                        Assign3.gridd = g;
                        Assign3.best=temp;
                    }
                }finally {
                    mutex.unlock();
                }
            }catch(Exception e) {}
        }
        System.out.println(Assign3.evaluate(g) + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
```

This is my code and attached below is the result- thread 3 does not even run to completion and does not execute and of the code after the thread.join().

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3Guz.png)

EDIT: just ignore the panel stuff, that is for a later part of the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is not `join` that is causing your problems.
2. If you were running out of memory, there should be an exception ... actually an `OutOfMemoryError` which would not be squashed by the following.
3. I suspect that the real problem is being **hidden** by this:

   ```
   catch(Exception e) {}
   ```

   That says: *"if something goes wrong **don't tell me**"*.  That is egregiously bad code.  At least print a stacktrace for the exception.
4. I don't know if this is related to the problem or not, but your use of `mutex` is strange.  Each thread creates its own `mutex` and locks its own `mutex` in the `run()` method.  This achieves precisely nothing ...
5. Actually, 4 *could well be* related to your problem, since your threads all appear to be reading updating shared state in the `Assign3` classes static variables.  Since you are not synchronizing the access to the data structure properly (because your use of `mutex` is ineffective) there are potential race conditions and memory anomalies, which may cause all sorts of strange things to happen.  (Including a 3rd thread breaking things.)
6. You do not need to extend `Thread`.  All you need to do is to extend `Runnable` and create an instance of that and pass it to the `Thread` constructor.  (This is not your problem ... but you need to know it anyway.)

When you fix 3), I expect you will get a stacktrace that give you some clues that will help you to find the problem for yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I have fixed 6. I am still not sure how 3) would be causing a problem here. And this is my first time programming with threads and mutexes so I apologize if it may be bad code, but could you tell me a more efficient way of using the mutex in this case? All I am trying to do is have it so that only one of the threads can change the global variables at a time.

Comment: The problem is not efficiency.  The problem is correctness.  You need to understand how locks work and what you are trying to achieve with them.  Then use them >>correctly<< to do what you are trying to achieve.  For instance.  If you want to lock all of the variables, then you need a lock that all of the threads can share.  But beware that if you lock everything, then only one thread will be able to proceed at a time.

Comment: Aside: how come you are using `static` variables for this?  They should have taught you that that is a bad idea.  Java is an OO language.  Use objects, not globals / statics.